# After protecting whole cells&how to allow adding or deleting rows in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have protected all cells in my excel file and unlocked some of the specific colored cells afterward. Now I have to be able to run actions like adding or deleting rows. Is there any way I can do this with EPPLUS? I basically wanna right click on row number cell(if I can call it cell) than I have to be able to add or delete a row, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the options in the Worksheet protection dialog, you should be able to enable inserting and deleting rows.